# \r\n as a part of UTF8 character?

Tags: language-agnostic, unicode, character-encoding

Is it possible, that some UTF8 symbol includes bytes 0x0D 0x0A as it's part? If yes, what are such symbols?
(that task that I'm trying to solve is reading textual UTF8 file from the certain point rather then from the very beginning)

Comment: Note that a line break is not necessary represented as 0x0D 0x0A in data. Different systems have different line terminator conventions. But if you know that 0x0D 0x0A is used *and* the data is in the UTF-8 encoding, then it is safe to scan a sequence of bytes to find 0x0D 0x0A in order to get to the next line break in data.

Comment: I wonder what happens if 0x0D or 0x0A is followed by a combining character. However meaningless and rare it is, it's a possible situation and I think the multiple code points here should count towards one... um... grapheme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, every byte of a multibyte encoded codepoint will always have the most significant bit set.

Bytes with values 0-127 in an UTF-8 stream are uniquely mapped to ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

No, every character from range 0-127 ASCII is represented "as is" in UTF-8 text. Each byte of multi byte characters have they 8-bit set. It's one of [adventages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Advantages) of UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

The single Unicode code point U+0D0A will be represented as the three bytes `0xE0 0xB4 0x8A` in UTF-8.  The two Unicode code points U+000D U+000A will be represented as two bytes `0x0D 0x0A` in UTF-8.